# Get URL script content in Node.js with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to fetch contents inside a script tag from a url using node-fetch and then trying to json parse the data but i keep getting a return undefined.

I'm trying to get the content from the variable game from the html below and then stringify and then parse the json but it returns undefined.

Page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="welcome-div">
      <p>Welcome to the my website</p>
    </div>
    <script> 
      var game = new Game({
        stage: "prod",
        servers: {
          v32306117: {
            id: "v32306117",
            name: "name #1",
            hostname: "hostname1",
            port: 80,
          },
          v32306125: {
            id: "v32306125",
            name: "name #2",
            hostname: "hostname2",
            port: 80,
          }
        },
        userGroup: 0
      });

      game.init(function() {
        game.assetManager.load([{
          "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/grass.png",
          "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/grass.png"
        }]);

        game.debug.init();
        game.run();
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Fetch function:

```
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");

    async function serversFetch() {
      try {
        const servers = await fetch("https://get-servers.herokuapp.com/");
        const data = await servers.text();

        const servers_data = data.substring(
          data.lastIndexOf("var game =") + 20,
          data.lastIndexOf("game.init") - 10
        );

        return JSON.stringify(servers_data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    (async () => {
      const data = await serversFetch();
      console.log('data', data);

      const info = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log('info', info.servers); // returns undefined
    })()
```

if i console log info.servers it comes back undefined but if i console log just info it logs the output below.

```
info {
        stage: "prod",
        servers: {
          v32306117: {
            id: "v32306117",
            name: "name #1",
            hostname: "hostname1",
            port: 80,
          },
          v32306125: {
            id: "v32306125",
            name: "name #2",
            hostname: "hostname2",
            port: 80,
          }
        },
        userGroup: 0
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running into is because `JSON.stringify` only works on JavaScript objects and `servers_data` is a string. What this results in is `info` being a string later on and that's why `console.log(info.servers)` logs `undefined`. When you checked `console.log(info)`, it only had the appearance of working correctly since it was logging the string value of the object. You could test this by performing `console.log(typeof info)` and you'll see it's of type `string`.

What you are looking for is to have `servers_data` be a valid JSON string instead of being a string of a JavaScript object (which is missing all those double-quotes around object property names which JSON requires). The first option might be to brute force it and replace those properties with properties wrapped in double-quotes, i.e. `servers:` for `"servers:"` (the colon is included to make it more unique, but it's still not bulletproof). That doesn't help you with properties like `v32306117` which are likely unique and can't be replaced easily using the brute force replacement which is looking for known properties.

The next option would likely be to create a parser for the string which could parse it into an abstract syntax tree (AST) for JavaScript. You could then map that to the AST of JSON easily and then reform it as a string using a parser which understands the AST of JSON. Most parsers which use ASTs can parse a string to an AST and create a string from an AST. These parsers are often written using a recursive descent parser. Though this is a great exercise for programmers, you could likely find some libraries which implement AST parsers for JavaScript and JSON. Also, it's a bit of overkill with what you are trying to accomplish.

The final option which I think would be the easiest to implement and easiest to maintain would be to use [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5), which is a superset of JSON. Using `JSON5.parse`, you could parse `servers_data` as is and not have to worry about JSON formatting. This is because JSON5 accepts properties without the double-quotes and is much more lenient about the formatting (double-quotes vs single-quotes, etc.).